# TortiseSVN over LAN?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I've been having to use Source Safe at work and it blows.
I'd like to switch to TortiseSVN but apparently when working over LAN things can become corrupt? Is that true? Is there anyway to bypass corruption?

At this point, even Source Safe is starting to corrupt things. (Terrible program...) Thanks!

Comment: No one should ever use VSS.  It might be the worst SCM system of all time.

Comment: @duffymo: I beg you pardon, but I wouldn't even call VSS an SCM. What about excluding "SCM" and rephrase to "It might be the worst system of all time"? ;-)

Comment: I was trying to be polite, but I think your comment is closer to the mark.  Well done, and kudos to you for having the courage of your convictions to speak out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TortoiseSVN works perfectly well over a LAN, together with a Subversion server.

There is a possibility in TortoiseSVN to work against a local, file based repository. If the file based repo is placed on a network drive I assume that things can break. Don't do that.

Source Safe tries to do sharing based on a network share without a proper server software. It is very error prone. Don't try to do anything similar with subversion.

The SVN server runs fine under both Windows and Unix. There are installers available for both platforms.

Comment: But from what I'm being told, the Subversion Server requires Internet Access. (Which we can't allow due to security reasons.)

Comment: It doesn't. It's perfectly fine to install a subversion server on a machine without any internet access at all.

Comment: I'd look at CollabNet Edge, it's an incredibly easy setup to get SVN working over HTTP (even though it's purely internal): http://www.open.collab.net/products/subversion/SVNedge.html

Answer (score 1):

I've run Subversion on my home machine without any problem.  (I'm using Git now.)

You shouldn't be going out on the Internet to access your work SVN repository.  I'm assuming that you'll host it on a server inside your firewall, on your network.

But it's perfectly correct to access Subversion over the Internet.  Lots of open source projects grant read-only access to anonymous users so they can access code over the Internet.  Where are you getting your information?  Time for a new source.

Answer (score 0):

Can't say that's happened at my place of work, and we're about 50 people.

Answer (score 0):

You've got it wrong - VSS is prone to corruption when run over a network. This especially applies over a WAN. VSS works by directly modifying the files in the VSS DB, and if there's a network glitch during file transmission, it doesn't realise and so stores the partial files in the DB quite happily. As you've seen, the larger the file or the flakier the network, the more likely you are to lose data.

SVN doesn't work like this, it uses a server application, you send the files to the server, it checks them and then it securely stores them. If there's a problem, it tells you.

Now, you can configure SVN to work with the files directly (using the file:// protocol instead of the more common svn:// or http:// protocols), this is often done by a server process that reads the data (like a backup program) but it is not recommended for ordinary use. People used to use it for local-only svn operation, ie where there is only 1 user, but no-one does that nowadays.

There are good installers that set everything up for you, the best known is [VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/) but there is [UberSVN](http://www.ubersvn.com/) too. Go grab one and use it, you will be much happier.